# How to change the String Style

Tags: java, android, string

Can we change the String Style in java from normal to bold...

Example: I wish to **change the String "Name" from normal Style to bold Style.** Any default 
method included in java?

Comment: Aren't you missing something ? In what context do you want to change the string? html or what?

Comment: strings are strings they dont have any properties like BOLD, ITALIC etc on them, are you trying to change font on say a JLabel or is it on web ?

Comment: I want to change the string font style in android.....Can i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is just the representation of some text. Applying some style information depends on the GUI framework you use: Swing, AWT, JSP, etc...

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit vague, but in Swing you can use HTML in order to do format the way your strings appear in components:

```
jLabel1.setText("<html><b>Bold text</b></html>");
jButton1.setText("<html><b><i>Bold and Italic text</i></b></html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends where do you want to change its style ?

If you are using Swings' components or AWT or something like that then surely you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

A String object in Java just holds the data. It does not have any styling associated with it. Display  styles are associated with the presentation components. You sure are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a GUI System like a JLabel, JTextField etc, then you can go two ways:

eg:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>My Text");
```

or

```
Font F = new Font("Calibre",Font.BOLD,12);
myLabel.setFont(f);
```

Hope that answers you Question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways,

Either **create a `font` by yourself** ,

> something like, `Font abc = new Font("Arial",font.BOLD,15)`
>   and for any of the `components` you can use the `setFont()` method to set the font for the component.

[See the javadoc for more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

**Use html,**

> Java supports html formating on all of its swing components.

Here is [How to Use HTML in Swing Components.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

> Any default method included in java?

So I suppose for you its better to use a font, while setting the style via html means, if only for *that* text ,its not *default* for the component.

This is a generalized answer, for more specific answer,ask more specific question :)